# Background remains the same even after changing background-image and colour in CSS

Tags: css, background, background-image

I am trying to edit the background colour of a section in css. When I use the live view in Dreamweaver, the background shows the new colour. If I preview the page, it reverts back to the original colour. If I view the page using Safari, Chrome, or Firefox, it still shows the original background colour. How do I force the background to appear as the new colour?

The original colour is a gray gradient. For testing purposes, I am just trying to put the background white. I have changed the background colour to white and put a white background in css using background-colour and background-image.

Here is my html code:

```css
#banner {
  padding: 10em 0 4.75em 0;
}

#banner .inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 55em;
}

#banner .logo {
  -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease, -moz-transform 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease, -webkit-transform 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity 2s ease, -ms-transform 1s ease;
  transition: opacity 2s ease, transform 1s ease;
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 0 0 1.3em 0;
}

#banner .logo .icon {
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: solid 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125);
  cursor: default;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2em;
  height: 2.25em;
  line-height: 2.25em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 2.25em;
}

#banner h2 {
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease, -moz-transform 0.5s ease, -moz-filter 0.25s ease;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease, -webkit-filter 0.25s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease, -ms-transform 0.5s ease, -ms-filter 0.25s ease;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease, transform 0.5s ease, filter 0.25s ease;
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.65s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.65s;
  -ms-transition-delay: 0.65s;
  transition-delay: 0.65s;
  -moz-filter: blur(0);
  -webkit-filter: blur(0);
  -ms-filter: blur(0);
  filter: blur(0);
  opacity: 1;
  border-bottom: solid 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125);
  font-size: 2.25em;
  margin-bottom: 0.8em;
  padding-bottom: 0.4em;
  color: black;
}

#banner p {
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease, -moz-transform 0.5s ease, -moz-filter 0.25s ease;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease, -webkit-filter 0.25s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease, -ms-transform 0.5s ease, -ms-filter 0.25s ease;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease, transform 0.5s ease, filter 0.25s ease;
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.8s;
  -ms-transition-delay: 0.8s;
  transition-delay: 0.8s;
  -moz-filter: blur(0);
  -webkit-filter: blur(0);
  -ms-filter: blur(0);
  filter: blur(0);
  opacity: 1;
  font-family: Raleway, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 200;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  line-height: 2;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
  #banner {
    padding: 7em 0 8.25em 0;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-size: auto, cover;
    background-position: center, center;
    margin-bottom: -6.5em;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00) 99.45%, rgba(0, 101, 162, 1.00) 99.45%), url(../../img/Unknown.png);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00) 99.45%, rgba(0, 101, 162, 1.00) 99.45%), url(../../img/Unknown.png);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00) 99.45%, rgba(0, 101, 162, 1.00) 99.45%), url(../../img/Unknown.png);
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00) 99.45%, rgba(0, 101, 162, 1.00) 99.45%), url(../../img/Unknown.png);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  #banner {
    padding: 12em 3em 12.375em 3em;
    margin-bottom: -4.75em;
  }
  #banner .inner {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 736px) {
  #banner {
    padding: 5em 2em 4.25em 2em;
    margin-bottom: -2.5em;
  }
  #banner .logo {
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  }
  #banner .logo .icon {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  #banner h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  #banner p {
    font-size: 0.8em;
  }
}

body.is-preload #banner .logo {
  -moz-transform: translateY(0.5em);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0.5em);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0.5em);
  transform: translateY(0.5em);
  opacity: 0;
}

body.is-preload #banner h2 {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transform: translateX(0.25em);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0.25em);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0.25em);
  transform: translateX(0.25em);
  -moz-filter: blur(2px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  -ms-filter: blur(2px);
  filter: blur(2px);
}

body.is-preload #banner p {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transform: translateX(0.5em);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0.5em);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0.5em);
  transform: translateX(0.5em);
  -moz-filter: blur(2px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  -ms-filter: blur(2px);
  filter: blur(2px);
}
```

```html
<section id="banner">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="logo"><img src="img/World Valve Logo Trans copy.png" alt="Logo"></div>
    <h2>ワールドバルブ株式会社 <br> Imagination & Creativity</h2>
    <p>我々ワールドバルブ株式会社は、多様化する市場のニーズに応えていくと共に、 流体制御における様々な機器、機材の供給を通じ、 社会、環境の発展に貢献し続けていきます。</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

I expect the background for this section to be white now but it stays the original grey gradient. Any help with what could be causing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In code snippet everything seems to be fine. I see that you've got still grey gradient in smaller resolutions and I'm not sure if it's intended. Try removing that and see if everything is fine. Also test it in incognito in Chrome (i.e).

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the late reply. I tried what you suggested and nothing has changed.

Comment: Do you have any other css files which may have an impact on this section or whole project? Some global variables or classes?

Comment: Figured it out! That section was being overridden by another css file. Thanks for your help!